# Google cloud video intelligence API samples for ruby

Tags: ruby, google-cloud-platform, video-intelligence-api

I am using google-cloud-ruby client library, I don't see any samples related to current implementation of google cloud video intelligence API. From where should I look out code samples of google cloud video intelligence API for ruby client library.

Comment: Yeah, the documentation is a bit lacking. Have you seen: https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-ruby/blob/master/google-cloud-video_intelligence/acceptance/google/cloud/video_intelligence/v1/video_intelligence_service_smoke_test.rb - a bit rudimentary but should give a place to start.

Answer (score 0):

You can find some example in Google Cloud documentation - [APIs and Ruby libraries](https://cloud.google.com/ruby/docs/reference) under `Video Intelligence API`.

Also in [All Video Intelligence code samples](https://cloud.google.com/video-intelligence/docs/samples) document you can find extra examples, unfortunately not each sample contains `Ruby` code.
I have created `Feature Request` in `Issue Tracker` to add more `Ruby` examples. You can find it [here](http://issuetracker.google.com/186623062).

You also can indicate that you are affected by clicking on `(+1)` button and follow that thread as all updates could be track there.